# Unable to push new changes from local repo to remote github

Tags: git, git-push

I have created a repo, added it to my local github, but I can't push the local changes to my remote github repository. What am I doing wrong?

Error returned (i.e. this status never changes after the commands below and the files on github.com don't change)

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   README.md
```

I have tried all the following:

```
git push --all -u
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.253.112)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:xxx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts     (/home/leo/.ssh/known_hosts).
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
Everything up-to-date

git push -u origin master

git push origin --all

git push origin master

git push origin master:master

git push

git push --all

git add .
```

Comment: Just to be sure, have you added and committed your changes before push command?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have made a change that you did not commit. Everything else is the same as the remote repository, but once you commit the change, there will be something to push.

```sh
git commit -a -m "Modified README"
```

The `-a` option adds ALL changed files to commit. The `-m` option sets a message.

To verify this, you can add the output of your push commands to give more information. Your push commands should work after you do the commit command.